# Adding Prefix in a existing column name SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have a table "Customers" and in this table I can 3 columns (ID, firstName, LastName).

I would like to rename the ID column to be ID_1

It is possible to add the _1 as a prefix?

I been trying to search for this but all the responses and solution that I getting are not accurate.

Comment: do you want change table field name or create an alias?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it has to change the filed name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want change the display fieldname use an alias

```
  SELECT ID as ID_1, firstName, LastName
  FROM Customers
```

To rename the field on the table you use the script **[sp_rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188351(v=sql.120).aspx)**

```
 EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'


 EXEC sp_RENAME 'Customers.[ID]' , '[ID_1]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: A small question, what if I want to have back the name, it is possible to perform the same step? executing the same script?

Comment: but when I try to use the script again I get the error (Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.)

Comment: Yes but invert the parametes `EXEC sp_RENAME 'Customers.[ID_1]' , '[ID]', 'COLUMN'`

Comment: Thanks I had to add a double quotes "" in the object name. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2):

To rename a column in table you should use sp_rename stored procedure  like this:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Customers.ID' , 'ID_1', 'COLUMN'
```